# twitter4j API - Connection refused

Tags: java, twitter, connection, twitter4j, connectionexception

I am running a code which lets my Webapp post a status update on behalf of the user. The code is working perfectly fine locally but when I bring it on the  Windows Server 2012 R2, I get a ConnectionException.

```
15-Sep-2015 18:40:59.128 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-12] socialmedia.TwitterService.updateTwitterStatus null
 Connection refused: connect
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=2fc5b7cb or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0e20763e
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[2fc5b7cb-0e20763e 2fc5b7cb-0e207614], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.3}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:178)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1598)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:205)
    at de.materna.cmo.socialmedia.TwitterService.updateTwitterStatus(TwitterService.java:37)
    at de.materna.cmo.socialmedia.TwitterService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.updateTwitterStatus(Unknown Source)
    at de.materna.cmo.campaignmanagment.CampaignService.deployTwitterContents(CampaignService.java:174)
    at de.materna.cmo.campaignmanagment.CampaignService.deployCampaignContents(CampaignService.java:167)
    at de.materna.cmo.campaignmanagment.CampaignService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deployCampaignContents(Unknown Source)
    at de.materna.cmo.controller.CampaignController.releaseCampaign(CampaignController.java:184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:136)
    ... 50 more
```

The properties are configured as follows

```
debug=true
oauth.consumerKey=CONSUMER_KEY
oauth.consumerSecret=CONSUMER_SECRET
oauth.accessToken=ACCESS_TOKEN
oauth.accessTokenSecret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
http.proxyHost=proxy
http.proxyPort=8080
```

The code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TwitterService {
private Twitter twitter;

@Inject
private CmoTask task;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
}

public void updateTwitterStatus(String status) {
    try {
        twitter.updateStatus(status);
    } catch (TwitterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TwitterService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

}

Strange thing is I got it running for a couple of hours. I thought it might have had something to do with my changing the configuration later on locally and that twitter didn't allow you having the same configuration on different locations. Now I made an update and it isn't working, again. I tried registering a different webapp and using those keys in the .properties file. Not working.

- proxy settings are correct
- firewall is turned off on the server

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Connect Error you getting on Server actually depends on the access on the server.
Please check whether you are able to access https://api.twitter.com from the chrome or any other web browser.

Comment: Yes, I am able to access it from the browser. So it shouldn't be that.